# How to get Amazon prices from API?

Tags: api, amazon-product-api

I would like to build an app that shows me the price history of products and notifies me when the price reaches a certain limit.

I know that some of these things already exist, but I'm also interested in learning how to build them and trying out some technologies.

This is my question:

how do I get access to the Amazon Product API without having a website?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not as easy as making a GET request the Amazon API. You must onboard your app or website by following their process so you can get an Auth token. You might want to look into third party API? but see [Getting Started with Amazon API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_GettingStarted.html)

Comment: What API did you use to get price history for a given amazon product using ASIN?

Answer (score 4):

Right now, there are two Amazon APIs:

- The older one is called Amazon MWS. You find its documentation [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/index.html).
- The newer one is called SP-API (abbreviation for Selling Partner API). [This](https://developer.amazonservices.com/) is their main page.

The access to both is only possible after registering as a professional seller (sic!), which costs a monthly fee (about USD 40). After registering as a seller, you then have to additionally register as a developer within your seller account.

If you do not want to pay monthly fees or register, you could also try webscraping their website. Here I do not now, what their policy is.

Comment: in Addition to this answer "Amazon MWS" will be deprecate in future as per Amazon
https://developer.amazonservices.com/ check FAQ about the same
so better go for SP-API